# Вопрос по списку кортежей Python

Tags: python

Как имея один список кортежей

```
[('Плотва',), ('Налим',),]
```

И второй

```
[(1, 0)]
```

Вывести только `"Плотва 1"` т.к. она как бы == 1, а Налим == 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [11]: from itertools import chain

In [12]: [f'{a[0]} {b}' for a,b in zip(l1, chain.from_iterable(l2)) if b]
Out[12]: ['Плотва 1']
```